# write times in NetCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf

While using the NETCDF4 package write times in netCDF file.

```
dates = []
for iday in range(84):
    dates.append(datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1) + atetime.timedelta(hours = iday))
times[:] = date2num(dates, units=times.units, calendar = imes.calendar)
# print times[:]
for ii, i in enumerate(times[:]):
    print i, num2date(i, units=times.units), dates[ii]
```

The times are right:

```
17669815.0 2016-10-04 07:00:00 2016-10-04 07:00:00
17669816.0 2016-10-04 08:00:00.000006 2016-10-04 08:00:00
17669817.0 2016-10-04 09:00:00 2016-10-04 09:00:00
17669818.0 2016-10-04 10:00:00 2016-10-04 10:00:00
17669819.0 2016-10-04 11:00:00.000006 2016-10-04 11:00:00
```

But while reading the netcdf file:

```
input_file = '/home/lovechang/test.nc'
data = Dataset(input_file)

times = data.variables['time']
# print times[:]
# print num2date(times[:], units=times.units)
for i in times[:]:
    print i, num2date(i, units=times.units)
```

Results:

```
17669813.0 2016-10-04 05:00:00.000006
17669814.0 2016-10-04 06:00:00
17669815.0 2016-10-04 07:00:00
17669816.0 2016-10-04 08:00:00.000006
17669817.0 2016-10-04 09:00:00
17669818.0 2016-10-04 10:00:00
17669819.0 2016-10-04 11:00:00.000006
```

Ncview shows the time is not the punctually hour.

[image: screenshot of Ncview program running]

So what happened with the times?
And how can I write punctually hour in netcdf file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the time units and datatype you choose, you may encounter floating point accuracy problems. For example, if you specify the time in `days since 1970-01-01 00:00`, 32 bit float is not sufficient and you should use a 64 bit float instead:

```
import datetime
import netCDF4

times = [datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1) + datetime.timedelta(hours=hour)
         for hour in range(84)]

# Create netCDF file
calendar = 'standard'
units = 'days since 1970-01-01 00:00'
ds = netCDF4.Dataset('test.nc', 'w')
timedim = ds.createDimension(dimname='time', size=len(times))

# Write timestamps to netCDF file using 32bit float
timevar32 = ds.createVariable(varname='time32', dimensions=('time',),
                              datatype='float32')
timevar32[:] = netCDF4.date2num(times, units=units, calendar=calendar)

# Write timestamps to netCDF file using 64bit float
timevar64 = ds.createVariable(varname='time64', dimensions=('time',),
                              datatype='float64')
timevar64[:] = netCDF4.date2num(times, units=units, calendar=calendar)

# Read timestamps from netCDF file
times32 = netCDF4.num2date(timevar32[:], units=units, calendar=calendar)
times64 = netCDF4.num2date(timevar64[:], units=units, calendar=calendar)
for time, time32, time64 in zip(times, times32, times64):
    print "original  ", time
    print "  32 bit  ", time32
    print "  64 bit  ", time64
    print
```

If you specified the time in `hours since 2016-10-01 00:00`, even an integer would suffice (in this  example).